# Android - установить фокус на SearchView

Tags: android, view, android-search-view

Всем привет! У меня возникла пробема. Есть SearchView (НЕ В Toolbar'e) и при открытии фрагмента нужно что бы она раскрывалась и показывалась клавиатура.

Пробовал уже разные варианты и на текущий момент выглядит как то так:

```
viewHolder.searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(view.findFocus(), 0);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    });
    viewHolder.searchView.setIconified(false);
    viewHolder.searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Пробовал делать по разному, но ничего не помогало. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/opportunities_map_search_size"
    android:background="#c9c9ce"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPD:**

Сделал как посоветовали в коментарии и получилось так:

```
viewHolder.searchView.setFocusable(true);
    viewHolder.searchView.setIconified(false);
    viewHolder.searchView.post(() -> viewHolder.searchView.requestFocus());
```

Но теперь баг, что при закрытии SearchView (нажав на крестик), повторно он не открывается. Поднимается клавиатура, можно вводить текст, но он остаётся iconofied

Comment: searchView.post(() ->searchView.requestFocus())

Comment: @SviatVolkov Спасибо! Но я нашёл ещё способ. В onResume прописать searchView.requestFocus();